# user defined R function which will generate observational data

Tags: r, statistics

Need to write  a user defined R function which will generate observational data from the below function including a measurement error term, , where  is drawn randomly from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation /1+||. Create the  values in your data set by drawing randomly from a uniform distribution between −4 and 4. Generate 2,000 observations: {(,),=1..2000}.

```
() = {1,        if =0 
       sin⁡()/, otherwise}
```

Please assist

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include your code attempt. And while you're doing that, also fix the formatting of your post, especially the mathematical expressions.

Comment: and whats the value for `lambda`?

Comment: userdefined <- function(x)
  
{ ifelse(x==0,1,(sin(x))/x)
  
}

Comment: I have created this function, I am stuck in the lamda part only ..It says Experiment with a range of  values

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include further information instead of putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

***observations*** *function* below takes ***lambda*** as argument. This will get you going:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- runif(n= 2000, min= -4*pi, max = 4*pi)

observations <-  function(lambda) {
                 e <- sapply(x, function(x) {         # error term one for each x
                                   e <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = lambda/(1+ abs(x))) 
                                   return(e) } )

                 y_fx <- ifelse(x == 0, 1, sin(x)/x) + e
                 return(list(x = x, y = y_fx))   
                                  } 


obs_5 <- observations(5)                              # observations for lambda = 5
obs_0.5  <- observations(0.5)                         # for lambda = 0.5 

plot(obs_5$x,obs_5$y, col = 'red' , xlab = "X(i)", ylab = "Y(i)")
points(obs_0.5$x,obs_0.5$y, col = "blue")             # lambda = 0.5, blue points
```

[image: lambda = 5 and 0.5]

Comment: Thank you so much.. This is so much help... Thank you again :)

Comment: Glad to help :) Please edit your question according to the comments of other users. Also whenever you post a question accept an answer which you believe works best for you.  This will help others searching for answers similar to yours.

Comment: Sure , I will do it I need some more help on this topic

Comment: Can I have your email address

Comment: Sure. you can post your question here. I will check and include in answer.